# Function overloading in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of C++ name resolution (and overloading) rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374588/list-of-c-name-resolution-and-overloading-rules)

What are the rules in C++ for how the compiler decides which function to choose ? 
(that's is given two functions with the same name - how does the compiler pick/prioritize one function over the other, mainly I want to know what types of casting the compiler is more willing to do when he chooses)

Comment: The rules are many... and complicated. All of this is covered in section **3.4** of the C++  standard

Comment: @Belgi - I see, I took what you meant by prioritizing in a different context.

Comment: @phs - had to be, vote to close (Belgi, learn to search before you ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already stated, the rules are fully described in the standard. As a basic rule of thumb, the compiler will select the overload that requires the least automatic conversions, with the caveat that it will never apply 2 user-defined conversions.

Integer types get automatically cast around a lot. So if you have a function overloaded on an `int` and a `double`, the compile will pick the `int` function if called with a constant that is an integer. If you didn't have the `int` version, the compiler would select the `double` one. And among various integer types, the compiler prefers `int` for integer constants, because that is their type. If you overloaded on `short` and `unsigned short`, but called with a constant of `5`, the compiler would complain that it couldn't figure out which overload to use.

Scott Meyers' book does indeed have the best explanation I have ever read.

Comment: "Scott Meyers' book". Could you be more specific by naming the title of the book?

Comment: For the life of me, I cannot find it now. +1 to anyone with the reference?

Comment: Scott Meyers' books: http://www.aristeia.com/books.html ; the reference is probably to either Effective C++ or possibly More Effective C++.

Answer (score 0):

The entire function name is comprised of what you called the function as well as the parameter list.  So, logically, 2 functions called the same thing but with different parameter lists both have different "full names."  My terminology is probably a bit off, so if someone wants to correct that, feel free.

Comment: say you have doSomething(int x) and doSomething(short x), which does the compiler choose when you call doSomething(5) ?

Comment: Ahh, that makes it more interesting!  Good question, and also beyond the scope of my knowledge.  I feel like it would depend on what the compiler considers 5 to be.  I'm inclined to say int, but I'm not certain at all.

Comment: It will choose the `int` version.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on the type of the argument(s). No casting involved if the type does not match it simply will not compile.

Comment: See my comment on MGZero's post

Comment: For what I know if you have void f(double x) and you call f(5) it comiles and 5 is casted to 5.0