# Ambiguous overload for operator when in different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading, ambiguous

File A.hpp:

```
struct foo
{
   int x;
} foo;

inline bool operator ==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

File B.hpp

```
#include "A.hpp"

namespace SomeNamespace
{
   bool operator==(const foo &lhs, const foo &rhs)
   {
      /* ... */
   }

   /* ... */
   void someFunction(const foo &foo_instance1, const foo &foo_instance2)
   {
      CPPUNIT_ASSERT(foo_instance1 == foo_instance2);
   }
}
```

The compiler error for the line with the ASSERT is:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator==' ...
```

So, the problem is that the compiler sees both comparison operators.

The definition in the global namespace of A.hpp and the definition in the SomeNamespace of B.hpp are ambiguous.

Why does the compiler not use the defintion in the SomeNamespace?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or it didn't happen.

Comment: And `foo_instance1` is....? Please try to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) when asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, corrected with edit.

Comment: And where is `foo` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the same function twice; what do you expect to
happen?  The compiler finds `SomeNamespace::operator==` with
unqualified name lookup, and `::operator==` with ADL.  Since
both have exactly the same signature, there is no way for the
compiler to choose one over the other.

As a general rule, overloaded operators for a type should be
defined in the same namespace as the type, and no where else.
(If the overloaded operator takes two different types, defined
in two different namespaces, I'd put the operator in the global
namespace.  But such cases are rare.)

Comment: I didn't know ADL also looks in global scope (if that's what you mean?).

Comment: @JamesKanze Can you explain the difference, please: [with struct](http://ideone.com/sSNBeR) and [with namespace](http://ideone.com/SsGflZ)?

Comment: Ok, is see that ADL is the actual "problem" since foo and its == operator are defined in the same(global) namespace. So this definition is considered as also the definition in the "local" namespace. Thx

Comment: @PetrBudnik The difference in what?

Comment: @jrok ADL looks in namespaces implied by the arguments; in this case, it looks in the global namespace because that's where `foo` was defined.

Comment: @JamesKanze Well, sorry - it was two links actually if you click on them... But I have more clean version: http://ideone.com/FLg8h1 Why this is no problem then?

Comment: @PetrBudnik I still don't understand your question.  In the code in the link, you're calling a function with `nullptr`, so ADL doesn't come into it.  ADL adds namespaces determined by the arguments.

Comment: @JamesKanze Oh, I see! I guess, I had misunderstanding about ADL. Thanks, I appreciate you helping to sort it out.

Answer (score 2):

In your program `operator==` is defined in Global namespace and Somenamespace.

So when you are trying to access the `operator==` then compiler is unable to resolve which function to call, as both functions have same signature ans both are visible to compiler.

So to use `operator==` defined in SomeNamespace you must use `SomeNamespace::operator==` and for the operator define in Global namespace you must use `::operator==`.

Comment: What are the lookup rules? I thought that the operator== in SomeNamespace is considered first since it should be found first.Isn't it that the compiler searches for names in a bottom-up-like manner(of the namespaces) and stops when the first correct definition is found?

Comment: its not about top-to-bottom or bottom-up. When you are compiling the code compiler has both the functions visible "at same time".

Comment: @shobi Can you explain the difference, please: [with struct](http://ideone.com/sSNBeR) and [with namespace](http://ideone.com/SsGflZ)?

Comment: @Juergen pls refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374588/list-of-c-name-resolution-and-overloading-rules

Comment: @PetrBudnik sorry i didnt get u.

Comment: @shobi Click on the links to see the code in my previous comment, please.

Comment: @PetrBudnik by default member functions of struts are public, so compiler see's defination of do_it function twice(in case of struts), and when u wrap that function in namespace do_it goes in different scope one in namespace so and other in namespace so::other.

Comment: @shobi I think you misunderstood me... What do you say about this simple version then: http://ideone.com/FLg8h1

Comment: @shobi Nothing wrong with it, but according to you it should not compile.

Comment: @PetrBudnik, you are misinterpreting me, according to me it will compile.

Comment: @shobi You are right, my mistake. I guess, I didn't fully understand ADL. Thanks, I appreciate your input.