# redefinition of a variable with a different type

Tags: c++

sorry for the question title but I didn't know a correct title for my problem. I have the following code example:

```
struct test {
    test(int a) {
    }
};

int main() {
    test(1);
    return 0;
 }
```

The above example code works. Now i do (in my understanding) the same a bit differently:

```
struct test {
     test(int a) {
     }
};

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this I get the following error:

```
error: redefinition of 'a' with a different type: 'test' vs 'int'
```

But in my opinion it gets really strange when I try this:

```
struct test {
    test(int a) {
    }
};

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    test((int)a);
    return 0;
}
```

the above example works again and really confuses me since I don't see the difference (except casting an int to an int). Can anyone explain what's going on? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is called *most vexing parse*. Clang is being [more helpful](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YfD5Hu) than GCC here: `warning: parentheses were disambiguated as redundant parentheses around declaration of variable named 'a'` `note: add enclosing parentheses to perform a function-style cast`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really tricky:

```
test(1);
```

This is a construction of `test` with argument 1.

```
int a = 1;
test(a);
```

The compiler reads this as `test a;` (instance of `test` named `a` – with default construction). That `test` doesn't even provide a default constructor isn't considered by compiler at this point.

The fix (found by OP):

```
int a = 1;
test((int)a);
```

Now, the compiler is explicitly told to read `a` as expression (but not as identifier).

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to give your `test` variable a name, causing `test(a);` to be a declaration of a variable named `a` of type `test`.

In the other cases, since `test(1)` and `test((int)a)` cannot be declarations, but must be some kind of call, your compiler will treat that as constructing a temporary object of type `test` without a name.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax of defining variables in C++ is kind of quirky...

When you do

```
test(1);
```

you create a temporary object of the `test` structure. This object will be destructed immediately.

But when you do

```
test(a);
```

you don't create a temporary `test` object, you actually define a variable named `a`. It's equivalent to

```
test a;
```

You can solve this problem by using curly-braces

```
test{a};
```

Or by using an explicit expression for the "argument" (like you do with your cast), as such can't be used as variable names. In similar situation where you need to disambiguate between variables and expressions it's common to use the unary `+` as in

```
test(+a);
```

Answer (score 2):

In **ISO C++ Standard (ISO/IEC 14882) 2003**, at section **3.2**:

> *In any translation unit, a template, type, function, or object can have **no more than one definition**.*

Please note that *The One Definition Rule (ODR)* is an important concept in the C++ programming language.

If you want to have many functions with same name (and **different signatures**, of course), [function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374588/list-of-c-name-resolution-and-overloading-rules) is a feature which you want.