# Overloaded Templates and non-template functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I encountered a problem about "Overloaded Templates and non-template functions".

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// print any type we don't otherwise handle
template <typename T>
string debug_rep(const T &t) {
    ostringstream ret;
    ret << t; // uses T's output operator to print a representation of t
    return ret.str(); // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
}

// print pointers as their pointer value, followed by the object to which the pointer pointsv
template <typename T>
string debug_rep(T *p) {
    ostringstream ret;
    ret << "pointer: " << p;  // print the pointer's own value
    if (p) {
        ret << " " << debug_rep(*p);  // print the value to which p points
    } else {
        ret << " null pointer";  // or indicate that the p is null
    }
    return ret.str();  // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
}

string debug_rep(char * p) {
    return debug_rep((string)p);
}

string debug_rep(const char * p) {
    return debug_rep((string)p);
}

int main() {
    string debug_rep(const string& s);
    const char * cp = "hello";
    cout << debug_rep(cp) << endl;

    return 0;
}

string debug_rep(const string& s) {
    return '"' + s + '"';
}
```

In the book "C++ Primer", they say the `cout << debug_rep(cp) << endl;` in `main` function will call `debug_rep(const char * p)`. However, through my test, it actually calls `debug_rep(const string& s)`. So, I wonder why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

The (re-)declaration of the `debug_rep` function *inside* your `main` function (its first line) is the issue, here. That local function declaration adds the non-template version that takes a `const string&` argument to the immediate scope, which then hides ('shadows') the templated version(s).

Any such local declaration of a function or variable will take precedence over similar names in outer scopes.

If you move that *declaration* to the global (file) scope, then the code in your `cout` line will, indeed call the function taking a `const char*` argument:

```cpp
string debug_rep(const string& s); // Declare in global scope

int main()
{
//  string debug_rep(const string & s); // Remove local re-definition
    const char* cp = "hello";
    cout << debug_rep(cp) << endl; // This now calls the `const char*` template

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can leave that local definition and add the scope resolution operator (`::`) to your call, to force name lookup in the global scope. (See also: [What is the meaning of prepended double colon "::"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4269034/10871073))

```cpp
int main()
{
    string debug_rep(const string & s);
    const char* cp = "hello";
    cout << ::debug_rep(cp) << endl; // Add global scope operator
    return 0;
}
```

---

I would like to add a citation from a C++ Standard explaining name resolution/look-up rules but, as stated in answers to [List of C++ name resolution (and overloading) rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7374588/10871073), the details are widely scattered around those documents.